# Covert ISO Date String to x days/minutes ago

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert a timestamp (e.g. `2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z`) to a timestamp that is 1 day or 1 minute prior.

Can someone help me fix this JavaScript function to get the desired output

```
aDay = '2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z'
function timeSince(date) {

    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

    var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

    if (interval > 1) {
      return interval + " years";
    }
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
    if (interval > 1) {
      return interval + " months";
    }
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    if (interval > 1) {
      return interval + " days";
    }
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    if (interval > 1) {
      return interval + " hours";
    }
    interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    if (interval > 1) {
      return interval + " minutes";
    }
    return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
  }
  console.log(timeSince(new Date(Date.now()- aDay)));
```

Comment: I have provided the answer you can check, also would like to know why you choose to do calculation rather than using build in methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*aDay* is a string but you're treating it like a Date. The format is about the only one that is supported by ECMA-262 and browsers in use, so you can use:

```
let aDay = new Date('2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z');
```

The *timeSince* function seems to want a Date, you're passing it a number that is the difference in time values between two dates, just pass it *aDay* as a Date:

```js
function timeSince(date) {

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

  var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " years";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " months";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " days";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " hours";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " minutes";
  }
  return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds";
}

let aDay = '2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z'
console.log(timeSince(new Date(aDay)));
```

That kind of expression is typically called a "friendly date", however many users (me included) don't like them at all and much prefer to see the actual date.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 day ago

```
const asd = new Date('2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z');
const dayDecreased = new Date('2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z').setDate(asd.getDate() - 1);
new Date(dayDecreased).toUTCString() // utc added just for time zone, depend on you
```

For 1 min ago

```
const asd = new Date('2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z');
const minutesDecreased = new Date('2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z').setMinutes(asd.getMinutes() - 1);
new Date(dayDecreased).toUTCString() // utc added just for time zone, depend on you
```

As I check your above logic,
Dont try to perforn calculation when we have inbuild methods to do that work, if you want any specific functionality which cannot be provided by build in method, than its fine to do that

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using MomentJS (https://momentjs.com/), a simple date / time management library :

```
const timeAgo = moment("2020-05-01T07:28:02.657Z").fromNow();
```